# Update SQL with two tables in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ora-00933

I have a sql like this

```
UPDATE A
SET A.TEMSILCI_KOD = 4
FROM S_MUSTERI A, S_TEKLIF B
WHERE A.TEMSILCI_KOD = 9
AND B.BAYI_KOD = 17
AND A.HESAP_NO = B.HESAP_NO
```

But i getting an error like this

```
Error starting at line 8 in command:
UPDATE A
SET A.TEMSILCI_KOD = 4
FROM S_MUSTERI A, S_TEKLIF B
WHERE A.TEMSILCI_KOD = 9
AND B.BAYI_KOD = 17
AND A.HESAP_NO = B.HESAP_NO
Error at Command Line:9 Column:22
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Where is the `ERROR`?

Comment: The multi-table `UPDATE` works on SQL Server, but not Oracle.

Comment: are you doing this in a procedure?

Comment: [RTFM](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10008.htm#i2067715), there's no `FROM`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
UPDATE S_MUSTERI
SET TEMSILCI_KOD = 4
WHERE TEMSILCI_KOD = 9
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM S_TEKLIF B
WHERE S_MUSTERI.HESAP_NO = B.HESAP_NO
AND B.BAYI_KOD = 17)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle the syntax to update a view is different from SQL*Server's syntax. In Oracle you could issue the following query:

```
UPDATE (SELECT A.TEMSILCI_KOD
          FROM S_MUSTERI A, S_TEKLIF B
         WHERE A.TEMSILCI_KOD = 9
           AND B.BAYI_KOD = 17
           AND A.HESAP_NO = B.HESAP_NO)
   SET TEMSILCI_KOD = 4
```

Note: This query will only work in Oracle if `(S_TEKLIF.BAYI_KOD, S_TEKLIF.HESAP_NO)` is unique (so that the update will not be ambiguous and each row from `S_MUSTERI` will be updated at most once).

Answer (score 2):

Your update statement does not follow the correct syntax.  There is no from clause in the update statement.  It should follow the format

```
Update <table> 
   set <column> = <value> 
 where <conditions>
```

See this documentation on update:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm#i2067715